# Angular Material FormField Notched Outline skewed

Tags: angular, angular-material

I've been working with Angular Material for years now. I just upgraded from v14 to v15.

```
"@angular/material": "15.2.7",
```

All of a sudden, all of my mat-form-fields, that have the appearence set to "outline", are showing a vertical outline bar after the label floats.

[image: Example]

To add, I went through all style sheets, and I do not override any styles other than width. I removed that "override" and it still behaves the same.

It only occurs when focused or active.

Any ideas?

Comment: please add a stackblitz so we can find the issue in your code!

Comment: Do you override colours ?

Comment: @Vega only in the material theme. I've got a custom primary, accent, and warn palette used in `define-dark-theme`

Comment: With browser dev tools inspect the line and the styles that are applied to it. Might be you have a custom class with the same name?